# Further writings by Rob Pike on software complexity and design

Tags: design

in "[Notes on Programming in C](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/pikestyle.html)", in section "Complexity", Rob Pike writes:

> Most programs are too complicated - that is, more complex than they
>   need to be to solve their problems efficiently.  Why? Mostly it's
>   because of bad design, but I will skip that issue here because it's a
>   big one. .../...

Does anyone know whether Rob Pike has written more about software design and how to avoid complexity, and where this might be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at Pike (and Brian Kernighan) book, "The Practice of Programming" (http://www.amazon.com/Practice-Programming-Brian-W-Kernighan/dp/020161586X).

[The Text Editor Sam](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/sam/sam.html) has some efficiency and design philosophizing in it.

Pike, sad to say, isn't amazingly prolific in terms of writing.

UPDATE: Rob Pike has a [blog](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/).  I found this blog after I wrote my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. That was on my to-get list. I guess I'll prioritize upward.

Comment: It's a pretty good book.  Pike is one of my programming heroes, so I bought and read it right when it came out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also reading through Sam of Plan9. Interesting.